# Why this firebase calling always returns null?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Consider the following firebase structure:

```
{
  "users": {
    "h7iStd4QvAYWh9xPbsiFuByDd1j1" : {
      "email" : "jobs@apple.com",
      "name" : "Steve Jobs",
      "rank" : 0
    },
    "wkA0DrJs9wdBlfAkJuKIrnhNzyq2" : {
      "email" : "gates@microsoft.com",
      "name" : "Bill Gates",
      "rank" : 0
    }
  }
}
```

and this data retrieval:

```
const email = 'jobs@apple.com';

firebase.database().ref('users').equalTo(email, 'email').once('value')
    .then((snapshot) => {

      console.log(email, snapshot.key, snapshot.val());

      // snapshot.val() always returns null

    })
    .catch((error) => {

      console.error(error);

    });
```

Why `snapshot.val()` returns null? What is the correct approach to fetch the whole object concerning Steve Jobs data, the child with `h7iStd4QvAYWh9xPbsiFuByDd1j1` key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
firebase.database().ref('users').orderByChild('email').equalTo(email).once('value')
```

Comment: Any idea why we need to order the results to get a val()?